# Android: download multiple images from Firebase-storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I download multiple images from Firebase storage and display them in app?

```
StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("capture6.PNG");
Glide.with(Retrieve_Data.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(imgview1);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the adapter where you are loading the data, there itself you can download image

```
if (Utilities.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
  mStorageReference.child("image name in 
      storage").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
Glide.with(Retrieve_Data.this).using(new 
 FirebaseImageLoader()).load(uri.tostring()).into(imgview1);
}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
Log.e("ERROR", "" + e);
}
});
```

Comment: i want get all images from one folder in my firebase storage

Comment: then you can get the storage reference in the model class and download it in adapter